# Unable to initialize com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$VaadinAppShellContextListener

Tags: heroku, vaadin, web-deployment

I have try to deploy my app to Heroku, but it's not working. I have try to follow the vaadin instructions, but it's not working. What's the problem?

#### Error on heroku logs:

```java
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$VaadinAppShellContextListener
2023-01-04T22:30:36.972557+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$FailFastServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:192) ~[vaadin-spring-23.3.0.jar!/:na]
2023-01-04T22:30:36.972560+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.lambda$contextInitialized$0(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:214) ~[vaadin-spring-23.3.0.jar!/:na]
2023-01-04T22:30:36.972561+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
2023-01-04T22:30:36.972562+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:214) ~[vaadin-spring-23.3.0.jar!/:na]
...
2023-01-04T20:56:40.962495+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-01-04 21:56:40.962  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 35531 (http)
2023-01-04T20:56:40.981852+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-01-04 21:56:40.981  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-01-04T20:56:40.982068+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-01-04 21:56:40.981  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.68]
2023-01-04T20:56:41.145481+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-01-04 21:56:41.145  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-01-04T20:56:41.145634+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-01-04 21:56:41.145  INFO 4 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4610 ms
2023-01-04T20:56:41.391728+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-01-04 21:56:41.391 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener]
2023-01-04T20:56:41.391750+00:00 app[web.1]:
2023-01-04T20:56:41.391753+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$VaadinAppShellContextListener
2023-01-04T20:56:41.391773+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$FailFastServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:192) ~[vaadin-spring-23.3.0.jar!/:na]
2023-01-04T20:56:41.391775+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.lambda$contextInitialized$0(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:214) ~[vaadin-spring-23.3.0.jar!/:na]
2023-01-04T20:56:41.391776+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
2023-01-04T20:56:41.391776+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:214) ~[vaadin-spring-23.3.0.jar!/:na]
2023-01-04T20:56:41.391778+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4767) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
2023-01-04T20:56:41.391778+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
2023-01-04T20:56:41.391779+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
2023-01-04T20:56:41.391779+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
2023-01-04T20:56:41.391780+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar!/:na]
...
2023-01-04T20:56:41.391815+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 50 common frames omitted
2023-01-04T20:56:41.391815+00:00 app[web.1]:
2023-01-04T20:56:41.392195+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-01-04 21:56:41.392 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2023-01-04T20:56:41.392932+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-01-04 21:56:41.392 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2023-01-04T20:56:41.446993+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-01-04 21:56:41.446  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-01-04T20:56:41.452376+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-01-04 21:56:41.452  WARN 4 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2023-01-04T20:56:41.464604+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-01-04 21:56:41.464  INFO 4 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
2023-01-04T20:56:41.464605+00:00 app[web.1]:
2023-01-04T20:56:41.464606+00:00 app[web.1]: Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-01-04T20:56:41.509555+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-01-04 21:56:41.509 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
...
2023-01-04T20:56:41.509566+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2023-01-04T20:56:41.509566+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar!/:2.7.5]
2023-01-04T20:56:41.509566+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar!/:2.7.5]
2023-01-04T20:56:41.509567+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:479) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar!/:2.7.5]
2023-01-04T20:56:41.509567+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar!/:2.7.5]
2023-01-04T20:56:41.509568+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar!/:2.7.5]
2023-01-04T20:56:41.509568+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar!/:2.7.5]
2023-01-04T20:56:41.509569+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 17 common frames omitted
2023-01-04T20:56:41.509569+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
2023-01-04T20:56:41.509570+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:187) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar!/:2.7.5]
2023-01-04T20:56:41.509570+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar!/:2.7.5]
2023-01-04T20:56:41.509570+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 22 common frames omitted
2023-01-04T20:56:41.509571+00:00 app[web.1]:
2023-01-04T20:56:41.752738+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

On my computer is working perfectly and i don't receive any error message.

Comment: Is the above the full stack trace? It seems to me that the root exception cause is missing

Comment: Did your build your .war in production mode?

Comment: Please check out https://martinelli.ch/running-a-vaadin-application-on-heroku/

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thanks, It's working, but the vaadin side menu is not working.

Console:
A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
xyz.herokuapp.com/:1 

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://xyz.herokuapp.com/') with script ('https://xyz.herokuapp.com/sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.

Comment: I have reinstalled the nodejs, and it has worked perfectly since then. Very intresting :)